# Executing a python script inside java map reduce

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce, processbuilder

I need to execute a python script inside a java mapreduce program.

Here, in the mapper class , I need execute the the python command :

```
 python methratio.py --ref=../refernce/referncefile -r -g --out=Ouputfile ./Inputfile
```

Here the Inputfile is the input file in hdfs and the outputfile (in hdfs) is where the python script writes the ouput.

Can I use process builder or any other better options are there ??

Comment: Not 100% sure the context, but are you trying to write a Java mapper where the implementation is actually handled by a python script? Are you actually using reducers? Have you considered using Oozie?

Comment: @mauzel Yeah. You are correct. The actual implementation is done by the python script. I am thinking about OOzie too. But I am confused which one is easy to do .

Comment: There is a decent amount of material on the internet on how to write a mapreduce job in Python, not having to rely on Java. The O'Reilly Hadoop MapReduce book talks about exactly that, from what I remember (it's been a while). I would try to Google "python mapreduce" and perhaps enhance your Python script to be the entirety of the MR job. (Or just write everything in Java)

Comment: Oozie is also a possibility. It's easy to use, assuming you already have it setup and have used it before. You can make Oozie exec your python script directly, but I've never actually done that before.

Comment: @mauzel The problem here is I should not rewrite or modify the python script since it is a old bioinformatics algorithm code. Thats Y I am searching for other options to wrap it

Comment: @mauzel I tried hadoop streaming but in that I am facing issue while reading/ writing files from/to hdfs inside the script

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, but you can execute system commands in this way in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = null;
        String command = "python <your_command>";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

You can see a detailed example in http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016

Hope this help you :D

Comment: you will need to make sure each node of your cluster has Python installed(not a given...)